# Create MongoDB capped collections in Meteor

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I'm new to Meteor and MongoDB. Could someone please provide a code snippet for creating a MongoDB capped collection in Meteor (server side and client side if it needs to be done on both sides). I have been searching for this for a few days now. I have found the code below but when I try it, the "Meteor.users" is undefined.

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';

const db = Meteor.users.rawDatabase(); // get the underlying db class
const createCollection = Meteor.wrapAsync(db.createCollection, db); // wrap into futures/fibers

// now create a capped collection called bob:
try {
  createCollection('bob', { capped: true, max: 100 });
} catch(error) {
  // do something with the error
}

// All being well we can now connect to this collection with
const Bob = new Mongo.Collection('bob');
```

I have also found the following code but when I try it I get -createCollection is not a function:

```
var coll = new Meteor.Collection("myCollection");
coll._createCappedCollection(numBytes);
```

Comment: Does it work for other collections? Have you checked the meteor core code on GitHub if the setup routine for Meteor.users uses the createCollection call in the way you expect?

Comment: I have not checked to see if this method works for collections that are not capped. For those collections I have just been using something like "coll = new Mongo.Collection(collectionName, idGenaration)" and that works fine

Answer (score 0):

You may not have any "accounts" packages installed in your app. Look in your app's `.meteor/packages` file to see if there any any packages present that begin with `accounts` (e.g., `accounts-password`). If not, try running the following in the root of your meteor project:

```
meteor add accounts-password
```